# multi-turn dialog slots confirmation in alexa skill?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dialog, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, slot

I wrote thsi code for individual slot confirmation in lambda.But, this doesn't work.Only it will call name slot not qualification slot.

```
// Confirm slot: name
                if(intentObj.slots.name.name == "name") {
                    if (intentObj.slots.name.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {
                        if (intentObj.slots.name.confirmationStatus !== 'DENIED') {
                            // slot status: unconfirmed
                            const slotToConfirm = 'name';
                            const speechOutput = 'Your name is ' + intentObj.slots.name.value + ', is that right?';
                            //  const repromptSpeech = speechOutput;
                            this.emit(':confirmSlot', slotToConfirm, speechOutput);
                        } else {
                            // slot status: denied => ask again
                            const slotToElicit = 'name';
                            const speechOutput = 'What is your name?';
                            //const repromptSpeech = 'Please tell me what is your name';
                            const updatedIntent = 'DialogIntent';
                            this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, updatedIntent);
                        }
                    }
                }

            // Confirm slot: qualification
            if(intentObj.slots.qualification.qualification == "qualification") {
                    if (intentObj.slots.qualification.confirmationStatus !== 'CONFIRMED') {
                        if (intentObj.slots.qualification.confirmationStatus !== 'DENIED') {
                            // slot status: unconfirmed
                            const slotToConfirm = 'qualification';
                            const speechOutput = 'Your qualification is ' + intentObj.slots.qualification.value + ', is that right?';
                            //  const repromptSpeech = speechOutput;
                            this.emit(':confirmSlot', slotToConfirm, speechOutput);
                        } else {
                            // slot status: denied => ask again
                            const slotToElicit = 'qualification';
                            const speechOutput = 'What is your qualification?';
                            //const repromptSpeech = 'Please tell me what is your qualification';
                            const updatedIntent = 'DialogIntent';
                            this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, updatedIntent);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

please share any information about the slots confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first slot's `if` statement will always come out as true.

> if(intentObj.slots.name.name == "name") { ... }

This is because the `slots.slotName.name` will always be the slot's name. It's a useless `if` statement.
You probably want to check if the slot is set and the value is not null. Then you can change your logic a bit.

```
if(intentObj.slots.name && intentObj.slots.name.value !== null) { 
    // check if confirmed or not
} else {
    // elicit slot "name"
}
```

---

Your second slot's `if` statement will always be false.

> if(intentObj.slots.qualification.qualification == "qualification") {

This is because there is no `qualification` key in the `slots.slotName` array. So just change it to be similar to the one above, checking if the `qualification` slot is set and the value is not null.

```
if(intentObj.slots.qualification && intentObj.slots.qualification.value !== null) { 
    // check if confirmed or not
} else {
    // elicit slot "qualification"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This code is working. it's very helpful to us